# Как фон, написанный на html и css закрепить, что бы он не съезжал от появляющийся информации

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image]

написал задний фон на css и html, но он съезжает от информации которую использую в верстке, как сделать так, что бы он был на одном месте, и был самым последним слоем, а новая информация была на переднем]

Comment: Читайте, что такое `position` и `z-index` в CSS

Comment: Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! Пожалуйста, приведите пример своего кода, добавить в сообщение его можно нажав на кнопку [edit]

Answer (score 0):

✌
Используй следующий код:

```
#фон {
    position: fixed; /* Установит фиксированную позицию */

    /* Поставит в верхний левый угол */
    top: 0; 
    left: 0;

    z-index: -1; /* Поместит под другие элементы */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-attachment
Я так понимаю вам надо использовать это свойство

```
 body {
background-image: url(images/help.png); /* Путь к фоновому изображению */
background-attachment: fixed; /* Фиксируем фон веб-страницы */
```

}